# How to store the result of query on the current table without changing the table schema?

Tags: sql-update, schema, google-bigquery, overwrite

I have a structure

```
  {
    id: "123",
    scans:[{
       "scanid":"123",
       "status":"sleep"
      }]
  },
  {
    id: "123",
    scans:[{
       "scanid":"123",
       "status":"sleep"
      }]
  }
```

Query to remove duplicate:

```
      SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (PARTITION BY id)
              row_number,
      FROM table1
    )
    WHERE row_number = 1
```

I specified destination table as table1.

Here I have made scans as repeated records, scanid as string and status as string. But when I do some query (I am making a query to remove duplicate) and overwrite the existing table, the table schema is changed. It becomes `scans_scanid(string)` and `scans_status(string)`. Scans record schema is changed now. Please suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: provide examples of your query that you have problem with

Comment: Mikhail..i have modified the question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that NEST() is not compatible with UnFlatten Results Output and mostly is used for intermediate result in subquery.

Try below workaround
Note, I use INTEGER for id and scanid. If they should be STRING you need to
a. make change in output schema section
as well as
b. remove use of parseInt() function in `t = {scanid:parseInt(x[0]), status:x[1]}`

```
SELECT id, scans.scanid, scans.status 
FROM JS(
  (      // input table
    SELECT id, NEST(CONCAT(STRING(scanid), ',', STRING(status))) AS scans
    FROM (
      SELECT id, scans.scanid, scans.status 
      FROM (
        SELECT id, scans.scanid, scans.status, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS dup
        FROM table1
      ) WHERE dup = 1  
    ) GROUP BY id
  ),
  id, scans,     // input columns
  "[{'name': 'id', 'type': 'INTEGER'},    // output schema
    {'name': 'scans', 'type': 'RECORD',
     'mode': 'REPEATED',
     'fields': [
       {'name': 'scanid', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
       {'name': 'status', 'type': 'STRING'}
     ]    
    }
  ]",
  "function(row, emit){    // function 
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < row.scans.length; i++) {
      x = row.scans[i].toString().split(',');
      t = {scanid:parseInt(x[0]), status:x[1]}
      c.push(t);
    };
    emit({id: row.id, scans: c});  
  }"
)
```

Here I use [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions). They are extremely powerful yet still have some [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions#limits) and [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions#limitations) to be aware of.  Also have in mind  - they are quite a candidates for being qualified as expensive [High-Compute queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute)

> Complex queries can consume extraordinarily large computing resources
>   relative to the number of bytes processed. Typically, such queries
>   contain a very large number of JOIN or CROSS JOIN clauses or complex
>   User-defined Functions.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you run the query on the web UI, the result is automatically [flattened](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#flatten), so that's why you see the schema is changed.

You need to run your query and write to a [destination table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data?hl=en#syncqueries), you have options on the web UI also to do this.

2) If you don't run your query on the web UI but still see schema changed, you should make explicit selects so the schema is retained for you eg:

```
select 'foo' as scans.scanid
```

This creates for you a record like output, but it won't be a repeated record for that please read further.

3) For some use cases you may need to use the `NEST(expr)` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) which

> Aggregates all values in the current aggregation scope into a repeated
>   field. For example, the query "SELECT x, NEST(y) FROM ... GROUP BY x"
>   returns one output record for each distinct x value, and contains a
>   repeated field for all y values paired with x in the query input. The
>   NEST function requires a GROUP BY clause.
>
> BigQuery automatically flattens query results, so if you use the NEST
>   function on the top level query, the results won't contain repeated
>   fields. Use the NEST function when using a subselect that produces
>   intermediate results for immediate use by the same query.

Comment: Pentium10.. I used case1) and even specified the destination table as table1. This too results in a changed schema.

Comment: Make sure you do not flatten your table.

Comment: Yeah i selected write preference as overwrite table and in results schema i unticked flatten results..but still schema is flattened. Now if i try to insert more rows with the previous schema, it throws error.

Comment: I want to thank google-bigquery team for the prompt reply to all my queries and making me aware about the positive and negative side of using any approach.